# Macbook Pro Trackpad 2-finger right click working intermittently

Tags: trackpad, multi-touch

My Macbook Pro 14" Trackpad is set up to **right click with a 2-finger click**. It has worked perfectly well until recently, and recently I am in a country with very dry weather. It works sometimes, like once in 6 clicks, and is super annoying.

If I do a Ctrl+Click the right click works, so I don't think its a software issue.

Could the dry weather and associated dry fingers result in this problem, or is it a Trackpad hardware issue?

Comment: They like a bit of moisture in the air, helps conductivity, but I've always found multi-finger gestures to be very hit & miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @Tetsujin is right, today when I tested it immediately after washing my hands, the 2-finger right-clicks worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Ha.. That's quite surprising. Has the solution consistently resolved your issue or does it still happen from time to time?

Comment: i can't say for sure, because i only noticed that when I was in a country with extreme dry weather for 1 month. Now that I am back to my home country that is very humid (on the equator) I don't have the problem

Comment: It sounded unlikely to me, but I definitely wouldn't go try reproducing it if it's working for now, haha